# Looping through ValueErrors in python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop

I have a list of dictionaries and a for loop

```
lst_of_dcts = [dict(keyA=True, keyB=10, id=0),
               dict(keyA=True, keyB=10, id=1),
               dict(keyA=True, keyB=10, id=2)]
final_dcts = []
for i in range(3):
    type_max = max((x for x in lst_of_dcts if x['keyA'] and x['id'] == i), key=lambda x: x['keyB'])
    final_dcts.append(type_max)
print(final_dcts)
```

How do I prevent the loop from breaking if a value for 'id' in the range of the loop is missing from the dictionaries? e.g.

```
lst_of_dcts = [dict(keyA=True, keyB=10, id=0),
               dict(keyA=True, keyB=10, id=2)]
```

results in:

```
ValueError: max() arg is an empty sequence
```

I tried with `if ValueError: continue` but this resulted in emptying `final_dcts`.

Comment: `if ValueError:` won't catch an error (and always evaluates truth-y), you need `try` and `except`. See https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html#handling-exceptions.

Comment: Thank you all for your answers and for the link to the official documentation!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try using a try/except clause to handle the exception and achieve the behavior you want:

```py
for i in range(3):
    try:
        type_max = max((x for x in lst_of_dcts if x['keyA'] and x['id'] == i), key=lambda x: x['keyB'])
        final_dcts.append(type_max)
    except ValueError:
        continue
```

As @jonrsharpe suggested, you can refer to the official documentation too: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html#handling-exceptions.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `try/except` block to catch it.

```py
lst_of_dcts = [dict(keyA=True, keyB=10, id=0),
               dict(keyA=True, keyB=10, id=1),
               dict(keyA=True, keyB=10, id=2)]
final_dcts = []
for i in range(3):
    try:
        type_max = max((x for x in lst_of_dcts if x['keyA'] and x['id'] == i), key=lambda x: x['keyB'])
        final_dcts.append(type_max)
    except ValueError as e:
        # do anything you want
        pass
print(final_dcts)
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively to using exceptions, you can iterate until `i` equals the max value of `id`. However, this is only viable when the `id` values are a continuous sequence of numbers (e. g. 0, 1, 2, ..., not 0, 2, 3).

```
lst_of_dcts = [dict(keyA=True, keyB=10, id=0),
               dict(keyA=True, keyB=10, id=1),
               dict(keyA=True, keyB=10, id=2)]
final_dcts = []
max_id = max(lst_of_dcts, key=lambda x: x["id"])["id"] # max id
for i in range(max_id + 1):
    type_max = max((x for x in lst_of_dcts if x['keyA'] and x['id'] == i), key=lambda x: x['keyB'])
    final_dcts.append(type_max)
print(final_dcts)
```